# Compute $\iint_Dxe^{x^2-y^2}dxdy$ if $D$ is the region bounded by the lines $y=x$, $y=x-1$, $y=0$, $y=1$

Tags: integration

$\int\int xe^n dx~dy$, where $n=x^2 -y^2$, where $E$ is the closed bounded region bounded by the lines $y=x$, $y=x-1$, $y=0$ and $y=1$.
I try it by drawing the picture made bg the condition. But I cannot integrate it properly. I find the limits.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing the region we find it to be a parallelogram,

[image]

Integrating first with $x$ gives:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{y+1} xe^{x^2-y^2} dx dy$$

Now let $u=x^2-y^2$, then integrating with $x$ for the moment we have $du=2xdx$. If $x=y$ then $u=0$ and if $x=y+1$ then $u=(y+1)^2-y^2=2y+1$. So we get,

$$=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2y+1}  e^{u} du dy$$

$$=\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} (e^{2y+1}-1) dy$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}(e^3-e-2)$$

Comment: thanks for hint@

Comment: sorry for asking just a easy math, I also allready done in a easy way after the question submit here. Thank you.